# How to pass Unicode title to matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, unicode, python-2.x

Can't get the titles right in matplotlib: 
`'technologieën in °C'` gives: `technologieÃn in ÃC`

Possible solutions already tried:

- `u'technologieën in °C`' doesn't work
- neither does: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of the code-file.

Any solutions?

Comment: Works fine for me : http://ideone.com/nhrP0m

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: That's because you got lucky and pasted in the right encoding for the IDEOne.com output encoding. Or your terminal encoding. But a terminal or the IDEOne.com page encoding is not the same thing as matplotlib-generated output.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to pass in *unicode* text:

```
u'technologieën in °C'
```

Do make sure you use the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` comment at the top, and make sure your text editor is actually using that codec. If your editor saves the file as Latin-1 encoded text, use that codec in the header, etc. The comment communicates to Python how to interpret your source file, especially when it comes to parsing string literals.

Alternatively, use escape codes for anything non-ASCII in your Unicode literals:

```
u'technologie\u00ebn in \u00b0C'
```

and avoid the issue of what codec to use in the first place.

I urge you to read:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

before you continue.

Most fonts will support the `°`, but if you see a box displayed instead, then you have a font issue and need to switch to a font that supports the characters you are trying to display.  For example, if Ariel supports your required characters, then use:

```
matplotlib.rc('font', family='Arial')
```

before plotting.

Comment: The only solution that works is this: u'technologie\u00ebn in \u00b0C'. 

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- in combination with u'technologieën in °C' doesn't work.

Comment: Then the encoding your text editor uses does *not* match the codec you specified in the comment at the top. If your editor uses the current windows code page, change it to `cp1252` (Windows Latin 1 variant) instead of UTF8, for example. Given that your text is Dutch (hoi!) that'd be my first guess.

Comment: <pre># -- coding: cp1252 -- </pre> doens't work. I work with Spyder.

Comment: I have no idea what encoding Spyder uses when saving a file, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Python and unicode is a real pain. Don't get it. .NET doesn't have that kind of trouble....

Comment: Yes you do but the tools hide it better. :-)

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) We use `utf-8` to save files in all major platforms (i.e. Windows, Linux and Mac) but we found a bug with PyQt4, Python 3 and unicode on Windows that will be fixed in our next release. Maybe that's what you're seeing here....

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, there is no need to worry about all that troublesome UTF-8 problems.

One note that you will need to set a Unicode font before plotting.

`matplotlib.rc('font', family='Arial')`