# matplotlib font with full utf-8 set

Tags: python, matplotlib, unicode, utf-8

The following is an extension of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525882/unicode-or-what-in-matplotlib#comment25485182_17525923). Am I wrong to assume that only *some* utf-8 characters are supported in matplotlib, at least with `DejaVu Sans` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960463/non-ascii-characters-in-matplotlib), but not others? Specifically, the [ballot x mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_mark) does not render, nor does the regular checkmark if I do not use the special [mathtext](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html) syntax.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
%pylab inline
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)

rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['DejaVu Sans']

plt.plot(t,s)
plt.text(1, -0.4, ur'$\u2718$', fontsize=20) # ballot x mark with mathtext
plt.text(1, -0.6, u'\u2713', fontsize=20) # check mark
plt.text(1, -0.8, ur'$\u2713$', fontsize=20) # check mark with mathtext
plt.xlabel(u'technologie\u00ebn in \u00b0C \u2713') # check mark after degrees C
plt.ylabel('volts (mV)')
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: what version of matplotlib are you using? I'm using 2.0.0 and all characters seem to be supported.

Comment: Works correctly for me with matplotlib 1.5.3. Are you sure that the DejaVu Sans font is installed? If so, try deleting your matplotlib font list cache in "~/.cache/matplotlib/".

Comment: I am on 1.4.2, that is probably the problem. I am using Python 2.7.10 (I know, but at the moment its necessary), OS X 10.11, Ipython 5.2.2

Comment: Getting to 2.0.0 did in fact solve it. I think I was actually not upgrading correctly with pip due to caching.